# Deploy war with native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, war

I am trying to deploy a compiled resource with my war.

In this case it is ffmpeg (but it could be anything else)

2 Things

1. So how do I include it in my WAR file
2. How would I use it (thinking more about the file location, what would be the path of the included executable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hierarchy of a typical war file:

```
/index.html
/login.jsp
/WEB-INF
/WEB-INF/web.xml
/WEB-INF/lib
/WEB-INF/lib/myapp.jar
```

You may include it in any of the directories or create one of your own. How you include it will depend entirely on your build system. You have to add that directory as resources directory, just as you would add a directory containing images or js files.

To use it, I would recommend using `getClass().getResource("filename")`. That will open an inputstream or you may use other methods to get a path.